# Is it possible to edit multiple arrays with a for-loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Is it possible to loop through a series of separate arrays like below?

```
var test;

var ratedItems0 = new Array();
var ratedItems1 = new Array();
var ratedItems2 = new Array();
var ratedItems3 = new Array();
var ratedItems4 = new Array();
var ratedItems5 = new Array();    

for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    test = 'test add num: '+ i
    ["ratedItems"+(i+1)].push(test);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe so, but why oh why would you want to do that?
Just make an array of arrays:

```
//init
var ratedItems = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
  ratedItems.push(new Array()); // Edited
}

// access
for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
  ratedItems[i].push(test)
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the scond for loop in this case be deleting the data in each spot that you added a new Array() in the first loop? Would it need to be ratedItems[num][i].push(test)?

Comment: Awesome. I think this will work great. Not saying the others won't but this just seems the cleanest. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should restructure your data as a multidimensional array:

```
var ratedItems = new Array();
ratedItems[0] = new Array();
...

for(var i=0; i<ratedItems.length; i++) {
    var test = 'test add num: '+ i;
    ratedItems[i].push(test);
}
```

Or, if you can't restructure that way for some reason, you want to reference each element as an attribute of `window`:

```
for(var i=0; i<6; i++) {
    var test = 'test add num: '+ i
    window["ratedItems"+(i+1)].push(test);
}
```

All global variables are member variables of the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting them all in a single object or make an array of arrays.

```
var test;

var bob = 
    {
ratedItems0 : new Array(),
ratedItems1 : new Array(),
ratedItems2 : new Array(),
ratedItems3 : new Array(),
ratedItems4 : new Array(),
ratedItems5 : new Array()
};

for(var i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    test = 'test add num: '+ i
    bob ["ratedItems"+(i+1)].push(test);
}​
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you. Does the splice method work just like it would on a single array when in an object?

Comment: You can do anything on "bob" that you could to an object, and anything to "bob[]" that you could do to an array.